# Grab Attributes from two Mono Objects and set them as a property to a third object using Reactor Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have two Api's that return two different Mono objects

```
Mono<User> user1 = api.service1(...);
Mono<UserV2> user2 = api.service2(...);
```

I want to grab a property from these objects say and set them to another object say SuperUser

```
SuperUser superUser = new SuperUser();
```

i want to do something like this

```
superUser.setProp1(user1.getProp1());
superUser.setProp2(user2.getProp1());
```

Once that is done, i want to send the superUser Object some method.

Comment: user1.map(usr -> usr. getProp1()).subscribe(System.out::println);

I have tried something like this, but how do i set it to object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat cleaner way to do it :)

```
SuperUser superUser = new SuperUser();

return Mono.zip(user1, user2).flatMap(data -> {
            String prop1 = data.getT1().getProp1();
            String prop2 = data.getT2().getProp1();
            if(prop1 != null)) {
                    superUser.setProp1(prop1);
            }
            if(prop2 != null) {
                superUser.setProp2(prop2);
            }
            return superUser;
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Zip the two monos and create the superUser from the tuple

```
Mono.zip(user1, user2).flatMap(data->{
    // get those values as below
    data.getT1();
    data.getT2();

    // set it to superUser
    return <your_response_object>;
});
```

Comment: thank you - i spent hours on this :'(

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mono#zipWith](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zipWith-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) like this:

```java
Mono<SuperUser> superUserMono = user1.zipWith(user2)
    .map(userTuple -> {
       superUser.setProp1(userTuple.getT1().getProp1());
       superUser.setProp2(userTuple.getT2().getProp1());
       
       return superUser;
    })
```